# Отправить данные на сервер по нажатию кнопки. Html

Tags: html, веб-программирование, arduino

Сервер у меня на ардуино, Ethernet shield. У меня не получается по нажатию на кнопку отправить POST запрос. Хотелось бы реализовать без JS, php вообще не обсуждается. У меня почему-то при использовании больших JS скриптов, просто не открывается страница, хотя, вполне возможно, что я что-то не так делал (Я убирал сам блок скрипта и сайт загружался, только была ошибка, что функция не объявлена, естественно). Если возможно, хотел бы увидеть пример создания двух кнопок и отправление запроса с одним или другим значением, в зависимости, от того, какая была нажата кнопка только на HTML, вроде бы это возможно. Полученные запросы я преобразую таким образом:

```
auto len = ether.packetReceive();
auto pos = ether.packetLoop(len);
if (pos)
{
  char *data = (char *) Ethernet::buffer + pos;
  Serial.println(data);
}
```

Обновление страницы даёт `GET / HTTP/1.1` и информацию по поводу соединения, User-Agent и т.д

Comment: Отправить возможно. Проанализировать нельзя. Какую Вы ожидаете реакцию на Ваши запросы?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Я же могу считывать полученные данные, далее буду оперировать ими

Comment: Я вообще не понял, какой PHP, какой JS? Обычная HTML форма с обычным submit

Comment: @AntonShchyrov ну да, просто всё что я находил в интернете делало запросы либо через XMLHttpRequest, либо через php скрипты

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну вот так

```html
<form method="post" action="my.html">
  <input type="hidden" name="data" value="1" />
  <input type="submit" value="Send 1"/>
</form>
<form method="post" action="my.html">
  <input type="hidden" name="data" value="2" />
  <input type="submit" value="Send 2"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Ого, спасибо большое, несколько часов гуглил и сам пытался сделать, но ничего не выходило, а это прям то что нужно.